# Default constructor prevents from calling emplace_back

Tags: c++, c++11

It seems that adding a default constructor prevents from calling `emplace_back` and produces the error message: "static assertion failed: type is not assignable" (gcc 5.3 with -std=c++14). Here is a simple code that illustrates the issue:

```
class A {
public:
    int a;
    A() = default;
    A(int a) {
        this->a = a;
    }
    A(A const & a) = delete;
    A& operator =(A const & a) = delete;
    A(A && a) = default;
    A& operator =(A && a) = default;
};

int main() {

    A a(4);
    std::vector<A> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(std::move(a)); // Error: type is not assignable
    return 0;
}
```

When removing the default constructor, the error goes away! Also, if the default constructor is defined (even if it does nothing), the error also goes away:

```
class A {
public:
    int a;
    A() {
    }
    A(int a) {
        this->a = a;
    }
    A(A const & a) = delete;
    A& operator =(A const & a) = delete;
    A(A && a) = default;
    A& operator =(A && a) = default;
};

int main() {

    A b;
    A a(4);
    std::vector<A> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(std::move(a)); // Error gone
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that "A() = default;" is what is causing the problem. 
Is this normal behaviour on part of the compiler or is it a bug?

Comment: [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c9da1c732899237) displays the same behavior as gcc

Comment: The code compiles fine with gcc 4.7.2 under c++11

Comment: It affects the trivialness of the class.

Comment: @SimonGibbons and neither clang [3.7](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77d028bd045b9c62) nor gcc [5.3](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8303732ae3158e7f) compile this with c++11 either...

Comment: @jaggedSpire clang compiles the code if you use libc++. This looks like a bug with libstdc++ where it's probably optimizing `emplace_back` for trivial types to a `memcpy` call, and that call chain involves calling a function that asserts that the type is copy assignable.

Comment: That's some ugly piece of code. If you start writing constructors, why would you want to resurrect the default one? Especially if `A(){}` is less typing ;)

Comment: @rustyx I am deeply hurt my friend (T_T)... Just kidding :). I believe in the principle that the more explicit the information given to the compiler, the better it can use it to generate better code. This is why I prefer A()=default instead of A(){}.

Comment: @jaggedSpire in cases like this where there's an intentionally-placed `static_assert` in the standard library headers it's usually pointless to test clang if you're going to use the same standard library headers.

Comment: @rustyx, `A() = default;` might be trivial, but `A() {}` definitely isn't. That can affect optimisations (as in this case, although here the std::lib's attempt to optimise has a bug).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a libstdc++ bug (edit: reported as [bug 69478](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69478)).

Briefly, libstdc++'s `std::vector`, as relevant here, uses `std::uninitialized_copy` (paired with move iterators) to move elements on reallocation, which is reduced to `std::copy` if the type is trivial and the iterators' reference types are assignable (i.e., the assignment operator that would conceptually be used is usable).

Then, the `std::copy` for pointers to trivial types (or in our case, a `move_iterator` wrapping a pointer) is in turn optimized into a call to `memmove` coupled with a check for `is_copy_assignable`. Of course, that check is wrong in this case, since the `uninitialized_copy`, paired with move iterators, only requires the thing to be move constructible.

When you don't have a default constructor or if the default constructor is user-defined, then the class isn't trivial, so you don't hit the code path that triggers this bug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.